# Android: BufferedReader trouble with special characters

Tags: java, android

I'm having trouble reading special characters coming from a `HttpsURLConnection` that receives a JSON string. When some JSON elements have special characters (e.g. `ã`, `á`, `€`, `Ç`) they'll be presented as `null`, e.g. the CTA element here has a `€` symbol in the middle of its text `{"duration":"17","cta":null}`

I can read everything perfectly except for the elements that have special characters.

Here's my code:

```
URL url = new URL(resourceUrl);
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")),8192);

String line;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null )            
    response.append(line);
```

I've also tried, with no success:

1. `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),"ISO-8859-1"),8192);`
2. `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"),8192);`

Comment: Well what encoding *is* the web server using? What do the headers look like?

Comment: Do the request in a browser, if you get `{"duration":"17","cta":null}` when there's a `€` in CTA, then the server is the problem and there's nothing you can do in the android app.

Comment: Thanks, this is hosted in GoDaddy (for testing), I'm in the process of moving it to EC2 as Godaddy is more trouble than it's worth. I'll check the server config and post back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, nginx encoding was UTF8 (confirmed on the headers), as were the MySQL tables.

Using an HTTP client like Postman still got me "null" as a replacement for special characters.

The problem persisted after changing Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1") to Charset.forName("UTF-8").

I solved it by setting the charset for MySQL at the connection level, on my.cnf:

```
[mysql]
character-set-client = utf8
default-character-set = utf8

[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8
init-connect = 'SET NAMES utf8'

[client]
default-character-set = utf8
```